# JSON dynamic value from API not showing on Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: javascript, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I'm pulling the total number of reviews from an API and I wanted to show in a Schema.org `itemprop="ratingCount"`.

Here's the API link: https://api.shopperapproved.com/aggregates/reviews/8149?token=m1n2JbxYqkDM7WNXhPdj&xml=false

HTML:

```html
<div>Rating stars based on <span id="ttlreviews" itemprop="ratingCount"></span> ratings and reviews</div>
```

JavaScript:

```html
<script>    
$.getJSON('https://api.shopperapproved.com/aggregates/reviews/8149?token=m1n2JbxYqkDM7WNXhPdj&xml=false', function(data) {        
document.getElementById("ttlreviews").innerHTML = data.total_reviews;
});
</script>
```

The page is showing the correct value. However, the Structured Data Testing Tool isn't catching the value (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fsazua.apleu.servertrust.com).

Comment: did you load the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

The Structured Data Testing Tool (SDTT) isn't very good at JavaScript.

I suggest you use the Google Search Consoles URL Inspection Tool. Do a live test and copy the html it gives you into the SDTT. You will then see what Googlebot sees.

Comment: I used the Rich Snippet Testing Tool and it seems to be catching the correct value. I will just wait and see what will display on SERP. Thanks.